# Markdown -> pandoc -> PDF, smart quotes not converted

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

My source text uses straight quotes, which pandoc converts to ``LaTeX quotes'', but those are coming through without being converted to smart quotes. I've even used the --smart option, with no change. I thought this was automatic, but apparently not. I can't find anything in my template file that looks like it would disable this. Is there another setting somewhere?

Comment: This should be automatic. What version of LaTeX are you using (e.g. TeX Live, Xetex, MikTeX, etc.) and on what operating system?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/fontspec-with-helvetica-breaks-quotes

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find anything in my template file that looks like it would disable this.

This sounds like you have a custom template file? In this case, you might want to **enable** [csquotes support](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example9/pandocs-markdown.html#smart-punctuation) by putting `\usepackage{csquotes}` into the template. Pandoc will then generate `\enquote{LaTeX quotes}` which might be more portable.